# Creating a customised version of printf

Tags: c, customization, printf, optional-parameters

What's the easiest way of creating a version of `snprintf()` with some additional features, such as an additional format specifier to repeat the following conversion a specified number of times? For example something like `%6a%-3x` would accept a `char*` parameter in the parameter list, and if this pointed to the string `"My test string"` would print `"4d 79 20 74 65 73 74 "`. The associated parameter would always be a pointer to an array of the appropriate type.

It's the code to interpret the format specifiers and the variable length parameter list (the types of which depend on the format specifiers in the format string) that I would like some help with, to avoid reinventing the wheel.

This needs to be in plain old fashioned C, since it has to compile using Microchip's C30 compiler for the PIC.

Thanks - Rowan

Comment: [Download an open-source implementation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/download.html) of `printf` and hack it.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart and then be forced to release all the rest of the code you wrote for the project, because it's a "derivative work". Absolutely nobody could object to that! That said, to the OP: there are more leniently-licensed stdio's/libc's out there; if nothing else, just pull one in from one of the BSD variants.

Comment: Guys, if you really think hacking printf is the right approach, you really need to check out vsprintf.

Answer (score 2):

[vsprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/vsprintf/) is what you are looking for.  It lets you write your own sprintf-like function that takes a variable number of arguments and then lets you do what you need before you make the call.

Here is an example where I used it to implement my own printf to a USB endpoint in an embedded device:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
void uprintf(char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vsprintf(str_buffer, fmt, args);
    usb_write(str_buffer);
    va_end(args);
}
```

In your case, you could "intercept" the format string before the call to `vsprintf` and expand your own syntax into proper format specifier syntax, then pass the new format specifier and the variable arg list on to `vsprintf`.

```
void your_printf(char *fmt, ...) {
    char new_fmt_string[1024];  /* make sure you allocate enough space */
    va_list args;

    /* here, do your transformation on the fmt string */

    va_start(args, new_fmt_string);
    vsprintf(str_buffer, new_fmt_string, args);

    /* now take your fully formatted string and do something with it */

    /* then clean up */
    va_end(args);
}
```

Comment: But there's no portable way to convert e.g. `const char(*)[3]` to a good argument list for `%-3x%-3x%-3x`.

Comment: I just gave him what he asked for:  It's the `code to interpret the format specifiers` and the `variable length parameter list` that I would like some help with, to avoid reinventing the wheel.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is likely not the answer you want, but it is probably the most practical solution: don't do it.

Instead, create your own output function that writes to the buffer.

```
// print count bytes from buf into s, but take up no more than n-1 bytes
// returns how many bytes were (or would be) printed
int snprint_hex (char *s, size_t n, const char *buf, size_t count) {
    //...
}
```

Your code will be clearer, and you won't have to implement arcane parsing code to deal with all the `printf` format specifiers.